# how to convert tangent function to degrees?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

I have seen in a book that:

$\exp (j*\tan^{-1}(4/3))=\exp (j*53.1)$, where $53.1$ is in degrees

How did he reach that value?

Note that $\tan^{-1}(4/3)$ can be seen also as $1/\tan (3/4)$

Comment: You are mistaken in thinking that "tan^-1(4/3) can be seen also as 1/tan(3/4)".  Almost surely your source has $\tan^{-1}(4/3)$, which is a common notation for the arctangent function applied to $\frac{4}{3}$, i.e. the angle in radians whose tangent is $\frac{4}{3}$.  Once you have an angle in radians, it can be converted to degrees by multiplying by $180/\pi$.

Comment: Matlab has builtin functions that take arguments (or return outputs) in degrees instead of radians: `sind`, `cosd`, `tand`, `atand`, etc. Also, please be professional and don't swear on StackExchange – even if it's an abbreviation.

Answer (score 0):

OK so i found out on my own with the help of matlab !!
Matlab is a great tool who saved me !

So the arctan(3/4) is the value in radians whos tangent equals arctan(3/4) 
arctan(4/3) = 0.927295218

[Matlab helped a lot !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tboY.png)